# How to target different levels of a Wordpress taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to dynamically target different levels of a taxonomy that are setup like this:

- Top Level Category

  -- Second Level Category

  --- Third Level Category

I've targeted the first and second levels like this:

```
<?php $parent = get_queried_object()->parent;
if($parent == "0"){ ?>
  Top level
<?php } else { ?>
  Second level
<?php } ?>
```

How can I target the third level?

---

```
<?php $term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$ancestors = get_ancestors( $term_id, 'categories' ); ?>

<pre>
<?php print_r($ancestors); ?>
</pre>
```

When on a category page with the code above... top level shows the array as empty, second level shows the id of the parent, third level shows the array with two levels. How can I target each individual level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with get_ancestors() WP function : [get_ancestors()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors)

```html
function get_tax_level($id, $tax){
    $ancestors = get_ancestors($id, $tax);
    return count($ancestors)+1;
}

$current_term_level = get_tax_level(get_queried_object()->term_id, get_queried_object()->taxonomy);

if ($current_term_level = 0) {
    // show first drop-down
} else if ($current_term_level = 1) {
    // show second drop-down
} else {
    // show third drop-down
}
```